# Any good Testimonial module / component in Joomla 1.6?

Tags: module, components, testimonials, joomla1.6

I am new to Joomla 1.6. I have a problem while trying to install "**`Freestyle Testimonials`**" (File Name - "`freestyle_testimonials_lite-1.6.0(1).zip`"), a component for testimonials for Joomla 1.6, as there is an error message appearing  "`Component Install: Another component is already using directory: /home/faster/public_html/webmaster/components/com_fst`". I cannot install the component.

Then I tried installing another module for testimonial "**`AutarTimonial`**" (File Name - "`mod_autartimonial1.6.zip`"). It installed and can be viewed under module manager but I cannot put it into my desired location (such as Testimonials menu), in the Admin area.

I am totally confused and asking for help.

Thanks in advance.

Subhagreen

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to fix the issue with Freestyle Testimonials you will need to delete the com_fst folder on your server. It sounds like the first install failed, but managed to make the folder which caused the second install attempt to fail.

Next, AutarTimonial is a module, not a component. Modules are designed to be placed in positions other than the main content area so there will not be a menu item for a module. AutarTimonial does have a component that probably goes with the module, you should install that, it should have the menu item you need.

You can also check out these other options: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/advanced-search-results/307991

Comment: I have deleted com_fst folder and tried to install Freestyle Testimonials but again the same message appearing "Component Install: Another component is already using directory: /home/faster/public_html/webmaster/administrator/components/com_fst". Please help me in this regard.

Comment: There are 2 instances of the folder, one in JOOMLA/components and one in JOOMLA/adminstrator/components. Make sure both are gone before trying the install.

Comment: Thanks again for the opinion. I have deleted folder "com_fst" from both of the joomla/administrator/components and also joomla/component directories. But still no work, the same message is appearing "Component Install: Another component is already using directory: /home/faster/public_html/webmaster/components/com_fst" 
Please help me to come out from this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Descriptions:

The JE Testimonial joomla component is one more useful utility for your Joomla-powered site that will provide you with a tool for managing and administering testimonials. JE Testimonial is the long waited component for the Joomla users from our extended brain search. It gives the in depth flexibility for using testimonials in Joomla based website.

Download link: http://www.jextn.com/joomla-testimonial-component

Demo link:  http://www.jetestimonial.jextn.com/

JE Testimonial - 2.0.0(1.6 Native) Released with default ACL Features.
Features of JE Testimonial – 1.2

Module Features :

```
* The admin can limit text length in module.
* Read more link. The admin can enable/disable this “read more” link.
* Ordering of Testimonial Display. a. Ascending & Descending based on Ordering b. Order by ID both ascending & descending. c. Order By name both ascending & descending
```

Component Features :

```
* JE Testimonial - 1.2 have three more display order settings. The admin can change these settings from the component back end.
      o The most recent first or the most recent last testimonial using ordering.
      o Order by ID both ascending & descending.
      o Order By name both ascending & descending.
```

Front end Feature List:

```
* Users can view the different type of template design depending upon the selections from the back end.
* Supports avatars/photos.
* Supports to add unlimited testimonial from the back end and front end.
* Visitors can add testimonial in the front-end with a simple form. Also admin can manage these details from the back-end.
* Show the authors name, url, location. But all are depending upon the settings from the back end.
* Front end testimonial form has captcha prevent spam.
* Admin can receive email notifications, when testimonials are added by the users in the front end.
* Display testimonials in the component and one of the associated modules.
```

Back end Features :

```
* Admin can Add/View/publish/edit/delete testimonials from the jetestimonial administrator panel.
* Jetestimonial component supports to translate all the major languages through the joomfish component.
* Choose whether to auto-publish new testimonial submissions.
* Choose whether the testimonials will be added by registered users.
* Choose the different themes from the backend and also can see the theme preview.
* Choose to display Number of testimonials per page.
* Choose whether you want captcha in the front end testimonal form.
* Manage the size of the avatar image.
```

New Features in JE Testimonial 1.1 :

```
* Removed the add ons in the front end editor and made it look better.
* The page title(form header) is now user friendly, so he can change to the name he likes.
* Implemented the parameters in the "Global Settings" for the User Form settings, to hide/show the city, country, email, company name and website fields.
* Implemented the support to sh404 component for user friendly url.
* Implemented a new plugin(content replacer plugin) for testimonial to display in the articles. You can replace the testimonials in the content area using {testimonial}
* Implemented the parameter in the "Global settings" for shadowbox effect, whether the external site links are opened in the shadow box or not.
```

JE Testimonials Module Features :

```
* JE Testimonial module has 4 slide effects with only one simple design.
* Settings for adjusting the modules with 4 slide effects.
* Admin can manage the specifications of this module.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback. But this JE Testimonial is a paid service. I would like to have a free component for my site. Could anyone help me in this regards?